# I can not use file input name in the post array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I was trying to upload several files together with CI framework. what I want is upload files to different folders. Therefore, I tried check file input element's name and set fill path.

Here is the code to get clear idea about my problem.

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|doc|pdf|docx';
        //$config['max_size']   = '100';
        //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
        //$config['max_height']  = '768';
            if($this->input->post('bankbook_attachment')){
                echo 'bank'.$this->input->post('bankbook_attachment');
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/bank/';

                $fillselect='bankbook_attachment';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($fillselect))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        echo 'error'.print_r($error);
                }
                else
                {
                     //   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                       // print_r($data);
                        $datame=$this->upload->data();
                        $fillnamebank= $datame['file_name'];
                        echo 'fillname is'.$fillnamebank;
                      // $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }


            }
            if($this->input->post('emp_nic_attachment')){
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/nic/';
                $fillselect='emp_nic_attachment';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($fillselect))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        echo 'error'.print_r($error);
                }
                else
                {
                     //   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                       // print_r($data);
                        $datame=$this->upload->data();
                        $fillnamenic= $datame['file_name'];
                        echo 'fillname is'.$fillnamenic;
                      // $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
            }
```

but when I run the code I notice that it doesn't validate if conditions, it leaves them.
In CI examples I have notice that they don't use post array to get the name but directly hard code. But which is impossible in my application.

How to solve this. I think simply problem is in this line `$this->input->post('emp_nic_attachment')`

Comment: Why do you need this `$this->input->post('emp_nic_attachment')`

Comment: I need to check which fill I am uploading and according to fill name file is sent to different folders to store file I upload.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are updating the upload directory in the `$config`, i don't think you have to check the 'fill name'. The below code would be enough

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/bank/';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('bankbook_attachment'))
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    echo 'error'.print_r($error);
}
else
{
    $datame=$this->upload->data();
    $fillnamebank= $datame['file_name'];
    echo 'fillname is'.$fillnamebank;
}

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/nic/';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('emp_nic_attachment'))
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    echo 'error'.print_r($error);
}
else
{
    $datame=$this->upload->data();
    $fillnamenic= $datame['file_name'];
    echo 'fillname is'.$fillnamenic;
}
```

Comment: but I am wondring why I can not get `$this->input->post('bankbook_attachment')`

Comment: and when I run above code I get the error : `The upload path does not appear to be valid.'. I think that's repeating same variable in the same scope. that's why I evalute in a if condition

Comment: The uploaded data is found in `$_FILES` not in `$_POST`. I think thats why `$this->input->post('bankbook_attachment')` is not returning anything. May be there is a `$this->input->file()` function in CI, not sure about that

Comment: have you checked it with one file element. ie without the `upload_path` overwriting. This will confirm if the error is bcoz of the `upload_path` repeating

Comment: @kiriappa it seems there is a `initialize()` for the upload object. Please check this [thread](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/94695/#d9) . There are some suggestions to upload files to multiple directories. Seems like an old post.

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours and forums help, I could find the answere.
simple and important concept is we have to load upload library and config file each time when we do multiple uploading.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/bank/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|jpg';
        $fillselect='bankbook_attachment';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($fillselect))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            echo 'error'.print_r($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                       // print_r($data);
                        $datame=$this->upload->data();
                        $fillnamebank= $datame['file_name'];
            echo 'fillname is'.$fillnamebank;
                      // $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }

                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/nic/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|jpg';
        $fillselect2='emp_nic_attachment';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($fillselect2))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            echo 'error'.print_r($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                       // print_r($data);
                        $datame=$this->upload->data();
                        $fillnamenic= $datame['file_name'];
            echo 'fillname is'.$fillnamenic;
                      // $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
```

another mistake I did was calling uplod library in constructor. It is uselss.